# c# open outlook with email and friendly names added

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, email

i am aware of the ability of:

```
"mailto:foo@bar.com?subject=MySubject"
```

but i want to know if there is a way to get the TO field populated in outlook but for a friendly name to be displayed (as outlook does) instead of the email address itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The mailto URL scheme](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2368)

```
 mailtoURL  =  "mailto:" [ to ] [ headers ]
 to         =  #mailbox
 headers    =  "?" header *( "&" header )
 header     =  hname "=" hvalue
 hname      =  *urlc
 hvalue     =  *urlc
```

"#mailbox" is as specified in RFC 822. This means that it consists of zero or more comma-separated mail addresses, possibly including "phrase" and "comment" components. Note that all URL reserved characters in "to" must be encoded: in particular, parentheses, commas, and the percent sign ("%"), which commonly occur in the "mailbox" syntax.

That said on a simple test the following seemed to work for me in Chrome opening Outlook

```
<a href="mailto:'Test' &lt;example@example.com&gt;">Contact via Email</a>
```